# Convert $z=2 -\mathrm{ i}$ in trigonometric form

Tags: trigonometry

I want to know what is the trigonometric form of $z=2 -\mathrm{i}$? Every time I lose myself in this exercise... I can never finish it. I really don't know how to do it.
Can someone help me?

Comment: @Qwerty I think internet connection problems should result in multiple similar questions, not a single question with repeated lines.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :**
$(a+b\mathrm{i})=r(\cos(\theta)+\mathrm{i}\sin(\theta))$ and $r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

To find theta use $\frac{a}{r}=\cos(\theta)$ and $\frac{b}{r}=\sin(\theta)$

Answer (score 1):

The trigonometric form of a complex number $z$ is expressed as $r(\cos \theta+\mathrm{i}\sin \theta)=r\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}$ where $r=\left | z \right |$. So, the magnitude is $r = \sqrt{5}$. Now we factor this out and get $\sqrt{5} \left( \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}-\mathrm{i}\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \right)$, and the angle is $\theta=\tan^{-1} \left( -\frac{1}{2} \right) \approx -0.464$. Therefore, we get $2-\mathrm{i}=\sqrt{5}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\tan^{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{2} \right)}$.